# Histogram Data Visualization in Python (using matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to StackOverflow. Recently I've been doing a web data scraping python project where I use bs4 to **scrape** the titles, publication dates, and author names from a website and store them into lists. Now I want to do some visualization using matplotlib to generate some visuals so I can put them on a website and host the website using aws.

The problem is that I have the date but I'm not sure how to use matplotlib for example, generate a histogram of # of articles being published each year, or names of the author who appear in most articles. Here are the lists I have rn:

```
#print(year_list)
# print(id_list)
# print(title_list)
# print(author_list)
# print(publication_date_list)
# print(abstract_list)
```

And snippets of printed year_list:

```
['2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2018', '2018', '2018',...]
```

Any suggestions about how I can use tools to visualize these lists?

Comment: You can find loads of sample codes for tasks like this by searching the 'net for (say) 'matplotlib simple histogram'. For instance, there's on sample at https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-histogram/ which might be useful to you. The way stackoverflow works is that, once you make a try at writing or adapting code for your own purposes, and have some difficulty, you come here with a specific question about how to resolve that difficulty. Normally we don't take on general how-tos like this here. But you're new, so no worries! And welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean, shouldn't you just be able to copy & paste an example like that on [pythonspot.com](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-histogram/) and simply replace its data with your data?

Edit: Replacing x in the example with your snippet from year_list produced this histogram: 
[image: year_list histogram]

Edit 2:
Just in case, the code is this:

```
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2019', '2018', '2018', '2018']

num_bins = 5

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yeah I tried it and it works! I think I was looking into matplotllib documentation and that was way too complicated.